# How can I use stat_bin2d with pre-binned data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to generate a `stat_bin2d()` plot but for **pre-binned** data;

i.e. Rather than raw points

```
x  y
5  3
13 4
13 14
16 12 
15 13
```

I instead have the data pre-binned with the corner points, in this case.

```
x  y  freq
0  0  1
0  10 0
10 0  1
10 10 3
```

I believe it might have something  to do with the data param of stat_bin2d but i can't find any doco on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_bin2d()` (with an "identity" stat), or just directly draw rectangles.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,10,10), y=c(0,10,0,10), freq=c(1,0,1,3))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(xmin=x, ymin=y, xmax=x+10, ymax=y+10, fill=freq), stat="identity")

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=x, ymin=y, xmax=x+10, ymax=y+10, fill=freq))
```